# How to follow an object in Corona SDK

Tags: android, coronasdk

I'm making a simple pong game and am wondering how to get the paddles to follow the ball movement.

The code I am attempting to use is

```
transition.to( upperpad, { delay=10, x=ballx, onComplete=listener1 })
```

where `ballx` is the current `x` value of the `ballx` and `upperpad` is the paddle that I want to follow the `x` value of the ball!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you translate "the paddle to follow the ball movement" into coding algorithm. If you simply want to set upperpad'x to be equalled to ballx all the time, you can just add following code in a [enterFrame event](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/enterFrame/index.html):

```
upperpad.x = ballx
```

The enterFrame function as explained in the URL is triggered every 30 or 60 times per second. So the pad is now following the ball movement all the time.